# Make 2 functions run at the same time in loop

Tags: python, loops

I am trying to make 2 functions run at the same time in while loop.

```
    import time


def func1():
    print('1')
    time.sleep(2)


def func2():
    print('2')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    while True:
        func1()
        func2()
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: check out example 1 here: https://linuxhint.com/python-multiprocessing-example/

Comment: Have you considered multithreading?

Comment: What is the behaviour you expect to see and what is the actual behaviour?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done by running the two functions in separate threads.

```py
import time, threading

def func1():
    print('1')
    time.sleep(2)

def func2():
    print('2')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    while True:
        threading.Thread(target=func1).start()
        threading.Thread(target=func2).start()
```